# validate ArrayList contents against specific set of data

Tags: java, string, validation, for-loop, arraylist

I want to check and verify that all of the contents in the ArrayList are similar to the value of a String variable. If any of the value is not similar, the index number to be printed with an error message like (value at index 2 didn't match the value of expectedName variable). 
After I run the code below, it will print all the three indexes with the error message, it will not print only the index number 1. 
Please note that here I'm getting the data from CSV file, putting it into arraylist and then validating it against the expected data in String variable.

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ValidateVideoDuration {
private static final String CSV_FILE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\videologs.csv";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String expectedVideo1Duration = "00:00:30";
    String expectedVideo2Duration = "00:00:10";
    String expectedVideo3Duration = "00:00:16";

    String actualVideo1Duration = "";
    String actualVideo2Duration = "";
    String actualVideo3Duration = "";

    ArrayList<String> actualVideo1DurationList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> actualVideo2DurationList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> actualVideo3DurationList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(CSV_FILE_PATH));
            CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader,
                    CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());) {
        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
            // Accessing values by Header names
            actualVideo1Duration = csvRecord.get("Video 1 Duration");
            actualVideo1DurationList.add(actualVideo1Duration);
            actualVideo2Duration = csvRecord.get("Video 2 Duration");
            actualVideo2DurationList.add(actualVideo2Duration);
            actualVideo3Duration = csvRecord.get("Video 3 Duration");
            actualVideo3DurationList.add(actualVideo3Duration);

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < actualVideo2DurationList.size(); i++) {
        if (actualVideo2DurationList.get(i) != expectedVideo2Duration) {
            System.out.println("Duration of Video 1 at index number " + Integer.toString(i)
                    + " didn't match the expected duration");
        }
    }
```

The data inside my CSV file look like the following:

```
video 1 duration, video 2 duration, video 3 duration
00:00:30, 00:00:10, 00:00:16
00:00:30, 00:00:15, 00:00:15
00:00:25, 00:00:10, 00:00:16
```

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: Try storing ArrayLists inside your ArrayList, that way the 3 durations are already grouped together.

Comment: Thank you Christopher for reviewing my code. Can you please help me how to do that? Please note that I need the ArrayList data to come from CSV file, it is a requirement to resolve this problem.

Comment: Thank you RisingSun for reviewing this code. The issue is that the for loop at the end of the code returns all indexes, however it is supposed to return only the index number 2 the value of which is 00:00:25 which doesn't match the value of the String variable which is 00:00:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `==` or `!=` for string compare. `==` checks the referential equality of two Strings and not the equality of the values. Use the `.equals()` method instead.

Change your if condition to `if (!actualVideo2DurationList.get(i).equals(expectedVideo2Duration))`

Comment: Thank you very much Ame, it resolved the problem. God bless you.